# blazor toast service from where i have this .toast:not(.show)

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

im boulding in blazor some webapp
found this tutorial about toast service - preaty basic stuff
https://www.gushiciku.cn/pl/2CEB

i did everything as in this tutorial and it was not working
i was searching why
and found that as on screen from some place - please tell me what

on build it is adding

```
.toast:not(.show) {
display: none;
```

}

as on screenshot

[image: screenshot]

when i remove this markup it is working fine
from where it is comming from ? i does not have this in any css etc , tryied to gogole but no luck...

thanks and regards !

-------- edit
i added show to @(IsVisible ? "show toast-visible" : null) and it works fine but im not sure it it is best solution ?

the issue is bootstrap 4/5 related. does anyone have similar solution using bootstrap 5 ands it toast component ?:)

regards once more.

Comment: Bootstrap css classes...

Comment: so why in this example it is not happening ? other version of bootstap?
i added show to @(IsVisible ? "show toast-visible" : null) and it works fine but im not sure it it is best solution ?

Comment: I think what @BrianParker meant was that the problem is Boostrap variables override the "normal" style of the Toaster Component. Do you have Bootstrap in your project? If yes the issue is here

Comment: The tutorial is 3 years old and only compatible with Bootstrap 4.0.  This version of Bootstrap did not have a toast component and so the tutorial adds entirely custom css classes.  However, this custom css conflicts with later versions of Bootstrap and specifically the class used to show the toast.  The tutorial should work if you use Bootstrap 4.0.

Comment: ok thanks  thats what i thought
i forgot  that blazor is so old xd
please post answer if you want i will accept ;) regards

Comment: The code in that tutorial looks very familiar to me. :).. Anyways have a look at this and yes its bootstrap 4. https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorToast I have not touched it in 16 months.

Comment: @BrianParker - It's actually a nice tutorial in the sense that it shows how to build a component without any javascript.  Too bad about the namespace collision.

Comment: does anyone saw similar tutorial / solution where bootstrap 5 ant its component for toasts used like this ? :)